# How can I get time of render page waste using Framework CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I get time of render page waste using [framework] [codeigniter]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter has a built-in pseudo-variable `elapsed_time` from the [Benchmarking Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html). You could use it within the view file :

```
<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds.</p>
```

Just like in the default `welcome_message.php` view file.